# 2015 MacBook Air fan constantly turns on after upgrading to OS X El Capitan

Tags: macos

Fan constantly turns on after installing El Capitan and opening a few applications. Any fixes for this or should I roll back the OS.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether any applications are constantly running and burning CPU by using Activity Monitor (Located in /Applications/Utilities).

If there are no applications burning CPU, try resetting the SMC:

1. Shut down the computer.
2. Plug in the MagSafe or USB-C power adapter to a power source and to your computer.
3. On the built-in keyboard, press the (left side) Shift-Control-Option keys and the power button at the same time.
4. Release all the keys and the power button at the same time.
5. Press the power button to turn on the computer.

Source: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295

Answer (score -2):

Safari seem to be the prob....with chrome no heating or fan crazy speed....

Comment: Could you back this up with any details? What sites cause issues for you?

Comment: bmike, If I knew what caused the issue I would have solved the problem already.